# What purpose of "as he did so" in the sentence

Tags: sentence-structure

> Harry shook his head, noticing **as he did so** that the ache in his right temple was getting worse.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix</sub>

I feel **as he did so** is kind of redundant. What additional information does it add here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of **as he did so** explicitly let us know that the act of **shaking his head** occurs simultaneously with the act of **noticing**. 
As pointed out in comments, as written by the author, the sentence could be paraphrased as:

> Harry shook his head, noticing at the same time that the ache in his right temple was getting worse.

Otherwise that sentence could have been interpreted differently.

For instance:

> Harry shook his head, noticing (then, later) that the ache in his right temple was getting worse.